# I want to add slug in my function using CodeIgniter but my code is not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, url, slug

I want to create a slug using CodeIgniter Web Framework but my code is not working I don't know why its happening, its giving me this error "redirected you too many times". 
Here is my route settings:

```
$route['readblog/(:num)/(:any)'] = 'blogs/readblog/$1/$2';
```

here is my controller

```
public function readblog($blog_id = null, $slug = '')
{
    if ($slug === '')
    {
       redirect('readblog/'. $blog_id . '/' . $slug);   
    }   
    else
    {
        $data['title'] = 'Blogs is here for shakzee';
        $this->load->view('home/header/header',$data);
        $this->load->view('home/css/css');
        $this->load->view('home/navbar/navbar2');
        $this->load->view('blogs/readblog',$data);
        $this->load->view('home/footer/footer');
        $this->load->view('home/js/js');                
    }               
}
```

Comment: it means the `if ($slug === '')` is returning true.

Comment: if add this code in my script its $slug = url_title($data['blog'][0]['blog_title'], 'dash', true); its redirect me on readblog but i want to set blogs before redblog

Comment: Your if condition means if the slug value is a blank string it would redirect to that page. Try making it not equals

Comment: You should be using == not ===. === is a comparison operator and means something is identical or of the same type. http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Answer (score 0):

Your condition `if ($slug === '')` creates a loop. Here's why. The function `readblog()` was just called with an empty string in the $slug parameter. The condition sees the empty string and then redirects back to the same function passing the same empty string as a parameter. The condition still exists so it redirects again, and again, and again. Eventually the browser realizes what is happening and issues the error.

You will need to do one of the following; set $slug to a valid string before redirecting back to the same URL; redirect to some other URL that explains the problem; load a view that explains the problem.